# Cannot parse config file using grunt command for execution

Tags: json, node.js, amazon-web-services, gruntjs, aws-lambda

I'm getting an error while working with grunt,

```
Error cannot parse config file unexpected token in default.json
```

I tried correcting the code but I'm receiving the [same error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1nma.png)

This is my default.json file:

```
{
    "Amazon" : {
        "lambda-arn" : "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:286506727102:function:myPandora",
    },
    "Pb": {
        "url": "https://aiaas.xxx",
        "app_id": "1xxxx1",
        "user_key": "070xxxxxx",
        "botname": "alexa"
    },
}
```

Please help me with this error, Thank you.

Comment: this is the blog which im following https://github.com/michaeljhopkins/pandorabots-alexa-skill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the commas at the end of lines 3 and 10 in your JSON to make it valid. E.g.

```json
{
    "Amazon": {
        "lambda-arn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:286506727102:function:myPandora"
    },
    "Pb": {
        "url": "https://aiaas.xxx",
        "app_id": "1xxxx1",
        "user_key": "070xxxxxx",
        "botname": "alexa"
    }
}
```